# Writing a function that outputs several regression results

Tags: r, matrix, regression

I have a mega data frame containing monthly stock returns from january 1970 to december 2009 (rows) for 7 different countries including the US (columns). My task is to regress the stock returns of each country (dependent variable) on the USA stock returns (independent variable) using the values of 4 different time periods namely the 70s, the 80s, the 90s and the 00s.

The data set (.csv) can be downloaded at: 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxaWFk-EO7tjbG43Yl9iQVlvazQ/edit

This means that I have 24 regressions to run seperately and report the results, which I have already done using the `lm()` function. However, I am currently attempting to use R smarter and create custom functions that will achieve my purpose and produce the 24 sets of results.

I have created sub data frames containing the observations clustered according to the time periods knowing that there are 120 months in a decade.

```
seventies = mydata[1:120, ] # 1970s (from Jan. 1970 to Dec. 1979)
eighties = mydata[121:240, ] # 1980s (from Jan. 1980to Dec. 1989)
nineties = mydata[241:360, ] # 1990s (from Jan. 1990 to Dec. 1999)
twenties = mydata[361:480, ] # 2000s (from Jan. 2000 to Dec. 2009)
```

NB: Each of the newly created variables are 120 x 7 matrices for 120 observations across 7 countries.

Running the 24 regressions using Java would require the use of imbricated `for` loops.

Could anyone provide the steps I must take to write a function that will arrive a the desired result? Some snippets of R code would also be appreciated. I am also thinking the `mapply` function will be used.

Thank you and let me know if my post needs some editing.

Comment: How about `lme4:::lmList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 install.packages('plyr')
 library('plyr')
 myfactors<-c(rep("seventies",120),rep("eighties",120),rep("nineties",120),rep("twenties",120))
 tapply(y,myfactors,function(y,X){ fit<-lm(y~ << regressors go here>>; return (fit);},X=mydata)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this code, but could you elaborate a little on its content please?

Comment: I don't think you need `plyr` for this. `tapply` is in the base package.

Answer (score 1):

The `lm` function will accept a matrix as the response varible and compute seperate regressions for each of the columns, so you can just combine (`cbind`) the different countries together for that part.

If you are willing to assume that the different decades have the same variance then you could fit the different decades using a dummy variable for decade (look at the `gl` function for a quick way to calculate a decade factor) and do everything in one call to `lm`.  A simple example:

```
fit <- lm( cbind( Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, Petal.Width ) ~ 0 + Species + Petal.Length:Species,
    data=iris )
```

This will give the same coefficient estimates as the seperate regressions, only the standard deviations and degrees of freedom (and therefore the tests and anything else that depends on those) will be different from running the regressions individually.

If you need the standard deviations computed individually for each decade then you can use `tapply` or `sapply` (passing decade info into the `subset` argument of `lm`) or other apply functions.

For displaying the results from several different regression models the new stargazer package may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 'stargazer' package for publication-quality text or LaTeX regression results tables.